# how to use regex for validate phone number?

Tags: regex

I want to use regex to validate a phone number.
Mobile number must be between six and ten digits
and there is no limit to spaces.

For example:

```
1 2345 false
123 45 false
12345 false
123 45678912 false

1 23456 true
123 456 true
123456 789 1 true
12 345 678 90 true
```

Now i use: `^[0-9\s]{6,10}$`, but this 1     7 is true.

Comment: SO isn't a free code-writing service. Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: i use '^[0-9](?: ?\d+){6,10}$

Comment: Your own attempt is what this post neede, you got my vote to re-open. You could start with trying: `^(?:\d\h*){6,10}$` which does not account for leading spaces though.

Comment: thank youuu mersiiiiiii

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate phone numbers using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/how-to-validate-phone-numbers-using-regex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```php
^ *(\d *){6,10}$
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/PZpS7Q/1/)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   *                       ' ' (0 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1 (between 6 and 10
                           times (matching the most amount
                           possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *                       ' ' (0 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ){6,10}                  end of \1 (NOTE: because you are using a
                           quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                           repetition of the captured pattern will be
                           stored in \1)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```